# Can't pass multiple documents in an array when using findById

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to find each of the elements in the array by their id and send it with the post request to create a new post. Right now when I create a new post only passes the first index of the array and if I use find() it passes all of the social schemas regardless if it is in the body of the request. I hope this makes sense if it doesn't please let me know. I hope someone can help.

Below is the mongoose schema for the qrcode post also using Joi

```
const Joi = require("joi");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { themeSchema } = require("./Theme");
const { userSchema } = require("./User");
const { socialSchema } = require("./Social");

const QrCode = mongoose.model(
  "QrCode",
  new mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
      type: userSchema,
      required: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: String,
      maxLength: 255,
      required: true,
      trim: true,
    },
    theme: {
      type: themeSchema,
      required: true,
    },
    // Social Media Links
    social: [
      {
        type: socialSchema,
        required: true,
      },
    ],
  })
);

function ValidateQrCode(qrCode) {
  const schema = {
    userId: Joi.objectId(),
    name: Joi.string().max(255).required(),
    themeId: Joi.objectId().required(),
    socialId: Joi.array().required(),
  };

  return Joi.validate(qrCode, schema);
}

module.exports.QrCode = QrCode;
module.exports.validate = ValidateQrCode;
```

this is the post route to create a new qrcode

```
router.post("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const { error } = validate(req.body);
  if (error) res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);

  const theme = await Theme.findById(req.body.themeId);
  if (!theme) return res.status(400).send("Invalid theme.");

  const user = await User.findById(req.user._id);
  if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Invalid theme.");

  const social = await Social.findById(req.body.socialId);
  if (!social) return res.status(400).send("Invalid social.");

  const qrCode = new QrCode({
    user: user,
    name: req.body.name,
    theme: theme,
    social: social,
  });

  await qrCode.save();

  res.send(qrCode);
});
```

In the body of my Postman request I am inputting the info below

```
{
    "name": "Friends",
    "themeId": "60f89e0c659ff827ddcce384",
    "socialId": [
        "60f89e43659ff827ddcce386",
        "60f89e5c659ff827ddcce388"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, I think you want to filter your social collection based on an array of input IDs. To do so you can use $in operator like this
Social.find({ "_id": { "$in": req.body.socialId } }

Answer (score 0):

To fetch data using ids, you can use below mongodb query simply,

```
db.collection.find( { _id : { $in : ["1", "2"] } } );
```

In mongoose,

```
model.find({
    '_id': { $in: [
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('1'),
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('2'), 
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId('3')
    ]}
}, function(err, docs){
     console.log(docs);
});
```

Or

```
 await Model.find({ '_id': { $in: ids } });
```